# MATLAB: Fix for accessing other properties in set function

Tags: matlab, class, oop, properties

MATLAB does not allow accessing other properties in a class within a set function.

However, one purpose of set function in the first place is to check for consistency. In my example, I want to make sure that the array which is set has a certain size:

```
function this = set.data(this, value)
    if length(value) ~= this.N % WARNING because property N is accessed
        my.exc.throwInvalidValue('Vector size is inconsistent');
    end
    this.data = value;
end
```

I do understand the reasoning (although I do not agree with it: a deterministic loading order would be more nice). However, I wonder what is the appropriate way to deal with this.

I could:

- Implement an actual method `setData` to do the job
- Check for consistency between `N` and `data` every time the class accesses them

Both of them are not a good solution.

Comment: The warning is: `A set method for a non-Dependent property should not access another property ('N').` and is described here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/avoiding-property-initialization-order-dependency.html

Comment: Looks like the linked duplicate has the answer: use [`dependent` properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-attributes.html)